# Eclipse - how to simultaneously switch working set for project explorer, call hierarchy, and search?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I switch working sets in the project explorer, the working set does not switch for the search and call hierarchy views, so I end up with search results from the wrong working set if I forget to switch those over manually.

Is there a shortcut for switching working sets in all those tools simultaneously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a special working set concept in Eclipse called *Window working set* which is basically a 'centralized' way of managing your working sets.

You can set up your working sets in *Window* / *Working Sets*. Most views which have support for working sets have an option to select this special working set (as you can see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm)). After finishing the setup you can turn on/off your active working set in *Window* / *Working Sets* and all views are automatically use the changed values.

Project explorer, call hierarchy and search support this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This sounds like exactly what I want.  However, my version (GALILEO, Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Build id: 20090619-0625) does not have a "Window | Working Sets" menu item.  The working set selectors in project explorer, etc. allow me to select a window working set (there are the three radio buttons, including "Window Working Sets"), but I can't figure out how to create a window working set.  Thanks for any more tips you can provide about this.

Comment: If you do not see that menu item go to Window / Customize Perspective..., select the Command Groups Availability tab and turn on the Window Working Set group. After that you should have that menu item in the Window menu.

Comment: This is such an amazing thing for my life. Eclipse should made this default :)

Answer (score 3):

To obtain some automation with Working Sets I suggest the following...

First of all a premise. All the views that support Working Sets ask you to select which one they are going to refer to. In the selection dialog, usually, you will find the name of the currently defined Working Sets AND the label Window Working Sets. The latter is, as Csaba_H was saying, some sort of centralized Working Set manager.

Therefore, make sure that every time you need to select a Working Set, your Window Working Set label is selected instead (in the search it's the last input field, press the Choose button...in the Package Explorer, it's the first entry above your WSs).

This is important because when you now change the WS selection within the Window Working Sets (sorry, a lot of WS here), you will automatically change all of them! You will see the Package Explorer change, for example.

As said here already, you can change it through Window -> Working Sets (if the entry is not there, just Window -> Customize Perspective... -> Command Groups Availability tab -> tick on Window Working Set). Not only that, now you can assign a shortcut under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Key -> Select Working Sets (category Window) and use the shortcut to open the selection dialog and change WS from there!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a direct way, but what you can try is (just for testing) to associate one perspective to one working set.
I.e. define a package explorer, a search view and a call hierarchy view:

- all set to working set WS1 in perspective P1.
- all set to working set WS2 in perspective P2.

That way, you should be able to switch perspective, effectively switching working set at the same time.