# Eclipse shortcut for switching current working set

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have several working sets in my eclipse which i often switch from one to another, is there any shortcuts for this so i don't have to click the "view menu" button and click the working set in it every time when i want to switch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up in `preferences/Window working sets.`
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934611/1130032) reference for your answer.

[Source](http://www.developersbook.com/eclipse/eclipse-keyboard-shortcuts.php)

Comment: Thanks, Now i can bind a shortcut to "select working set" command, when the "select working set" dialog appear, i check one and click OK, but my working set does not actually change, Any ideas?

Comment: I select the "Windows Working Sets", and next time when i use shortcut, it works:)